# How can I align a widget to the center of a Row and align the other 2 widgets to the center of each remaining space?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[Link to the printscreen of the figma model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNnUa.png)

I want to place the VerticalDivider widget right in the middle of the Row with the other 2 Columns that contain "Objetivo: Recomendação médica" and "Nível do aluno: intermediário" and I want both of these Columns in the middle of the space left for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Expanded` to split remaining spaces in a `Flex` (like `Row` or `Column`).

For example:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue)),
    VerticalDivider(),
    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.orange)),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked just fine, thank you so much :)